# main() variable is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter, error-handling

I wrote the code to create the game "Snake" in Python and gives an error saying that the main () variable is not defined, please help, it is very necessary:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 82, in <module>
    main()
NameError: name 'main' is not defined
```

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
SEG_SIZE = 20
IN_GAME = True

def create_block():

    global BLOCK
    posx = SEG_SIZE * random.randint(1, (WIDTH-SEG_SIZE)/SEG_SIZE)
    posy = SEG_SIZE * random.randint(1, (WIDTH-SEG_SIZE)/SEG_SIZE)
    BLOCK = c.create_oval(posx, posy,
                          posx+SEG_SIZE, posy+SEG_SIZE,
                          fill="red")
    def main():
        global IN_GAME
        if IN_GAME:
            s.move()
            head_coords = c.coords(s.segments[-1].instance)
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = head_coords
            if x2 > WIDTH or x1 < 0 or y1 < 0 or y2 > HEIGHT:
                IN_GAME = False
            elif head_coords == c.coords(BLOCK):
                s.add_segment()
                c.delete(BLOCK)
                create_block()
            else:
                for index in range(len(s.segments)-1):
                    if head_coords == c.coords(s.segments[index].instance):
                        IN_GAME = False
            root.after(100, main)
        else:
                c.create_text(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2,
                       text="GAME OVER! SAS",
                       fant="Arial 20",
                       fill="red")
class Segment(object):
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.instance = c.create_rectangle(x, y,
                                       x+SEG_SIZE, y+SEG_SIZE,
                                       fill="white")
class Snake(object):
     def __init__(self, segments):
        self.segments = segments
        self.mapping = {"Down": (0, 1), "Right": (1, 0),
                        "Up": (0, -1), "Left": (-1, 0)}
        self.vector = self.mapping["Right"]
     def move(self):
        for index in range(len(self.segments)-1):
           segment = self.segments[index].instance
           c.coords(segment, x1, y1, x2, y2)

        x1, y1, x2, y2 = c.coords(self.segments[-2].instance)
        c.coords(self.segments[-1].instance,
                 x1+self.vector[0]*SEG_SIZE, y1+self.vector[1]*SEG_SIZE,
                 x2+self.vector[0]*SEG_SIZE, y2+self.vector[1]*SEG_SIZE)
     def add_segment(self):
         last_seg = c.coords(self.segments[0].instance)
         x = last_seg[2] - SEG_SIZE
         y = last_seg[3] - SEG_SIZE
         self.segments.insert(0, Segment(x, y))

     def change_direction(self, event):
         if event.keysym in self.mapping:
             self.vector = self.mapping[event.keysym]
root = Tk()
root.title("Snake")


c = Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg="#003300")
c.grid()
c.focus_set()
segments = [Segment(SEG_SIZE, SEG_SIZE),
            Segment(SEG_SIZE*2, SEG_SIZE),
            Segment(SEG_SIZE*3, SEG_SIZE)]
s = Snake(segments)
c.bind("<KeyPress>", s.change_direction)

create_block()
main()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `def main():` is local to `def create_block` Read up on [Tutorial - 9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Comment: This is an English Q&A, but this Q is not. Please translate.

Comment: @HelpingHand Use [google translate](https://translate.google.com).

Comment: @TheMaker - No. See [this part of FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content/297680#297680) for clarification and [this link](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) for a native russian version of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Here. I completely reworked your code, and it runs without error. However, the game isn't playable, because you haven't coded that yet.

Code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import random

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
SEG_SIZE = 20
IN_GAME = True

root = Tk()
root.title("Snake")

c = Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg="#003300")
c.grid()
c.focus_set()

posx = SEG_SIZE * random.randint(1, (WIDTH-SEG_SIZE)/SEG_SIZE)
posy = SEG_SIZE * random.randint(1, (WIDTH-SEG_SIZE)/SEG_SIZE)
BLOCK = c.create_oval(posx, posy,
                      posx+SEG_SIZE, posy+SEG_SIZE,
                      fill="red")
def main():
    global IN_GAME
    if IN_GAME:
        s.move()
        head_coords = c.coords(s.segments[-1].instance)
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = head_coords
        if x2 > WIDTH or x1 < 0 or y1 < 0 or y2 > HEIGHT:
            IN_GAME = False
        elif head_coords == c.coords(BLOCK):
            s.add_segment()
            c.delete(BLOCK)
            create_block()
        else:
            for index in range(len(s.segments)-1):
                if head_coords == c.coords(s.segments[index].instance):
                    IN_GAME = False
        root.after(100, main)
    else:
            c.create_text(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2,
                   text="GAME OVER! SAS",
                   fant="Arial 20",
                   fill="red")
class Segment(object):
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.instance = c.create_rectangle(x, y,
                                       x+SEG_SIZE, y+SEG_SIZE,
                                       fill="white")
class Snake(object):
     def __init__(self, segments):
        self.segments = segments
        self.mapping = {"Down": (0, 1), "Right": (1, 0),
                        "Up": (0, -1), "Left": (-1, 0)}
        self.vector = self.mapping["Right"]
     def move(self):
        global x1, y1, x2, y2
        for index in range(len(self.segments)-1):
            segment = self.segments[index].instance
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = c.coords(self.segments[-2].instance)
            c.coords(segment, x1, y1, x2,
            y2)

        c.coords(self.segments[-1].instance,
                 x1+self.vector[0]*SEG_SIZE, y1+self.vector[1]*SEG_SIZE,
                 x2+self.vector[0]*SEG_SIZE, y2+self.vector[1]*SEG_SIZE)
     def add_segment(self):
         last_seg = c.coords(self.segments[0].instance)
         x = last_seg[2] - SEG_SIZE
         y = last_seg[3] - SEG_SIZE
         self.segments.insert(0, Segment(x, y))

     def change_direction(self, event):
         if event.keysym in self.mapping:
              self.vector = self.mapping[event.keysym]

segments = [Segment(SEG_SIZE, SEG_SIZE),
            Segment(SEG_SIZE*2, SEG_SIZE),
            Segment(SEG_SIZE*3, SEG_SIZE)]
s = Snake(segments)

c.bind("<KeyPress>", s.change_direction)

main()
root.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps!!

Note: If you want me to make the entire game, I'll gladly do it for free :)